# Append columns with values from has many reletionship

Tags: postgresql, join, alias

I have two tables `orders` and `items`. Every `Order` `has many` `Items`.

```
orders
- id
- created_at
- paid_at

items
- id
- title
- amount
- quantity
- order_id
```

Let say that there are 3 kinds of items. Chair, table and door.

I would like to create a query that will produce table with following columns:

```
- order_id
- created_at
- paid_at
- item_id # for chair
- item_title
- item_quantity
- item_amount
- item_id # for table
- item_title
- item_quantity
- item_amount
- item_id # for door
- item_title
- item_quantity
- item_amount
```

If order has chair item, data in columns for chair will be displayed otherwise it will be empty.

**Why am I doing this?**

I would like to export this data to excel sheet.

There is limited amount of different items so there is no problem with milions of columns.

Comment: So, if an order has 20 items, you want 20x4+3 = 83 columns?

Comment: How will you name the columns?

Comment: @ypercube you are correct. However, there are only 8 distinct items.

Comment: @Colin'tHart with arbitrary names: item1, item2...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join to a single table multiple times. Just use different aliases.

And use [`LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) to accommodate for the possibility of missing rows.

*Assuming* there can only be a *single* instance of chair, table and door attached to each order. You did not specify that, but your question would hardly make sense otherwise.

I introduce `item_type` in the table items to make this work. Consider the [schema in the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/cbba2/1).

```
SELECT o.id AS order_id, o.created_at, o.paid_at
      ,c.id       AS chair_id
      ,c.title    AS chair_title
      ,c.quantity AS chair_quantity
      ,c.amount   AS chair_amount

      ,t.id       AS table_id
      ,t.title    AS itable_title
      ,t.quantity AS table_quantity
      ,t.amount   AS table_amount

      ,d.id       AS door_id
      ,d.title    AS door_title
      ,d.quantity AS door_quantity
      ,d.amount   AS door_amount
FROM   orders o
LEFT   JOIN items AS c ON c.id = o.id AND c.item_type = 'chair'
LEFT   JOIN items AS t ON t.id = o.id AND t.item_type = 'table'
LEFT   JOIN items AS d ON d.id = o.id AND d.item_type = 'door';
```

Use distinct column aliases to make this work.

[-> SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/cbba2/1)

Comment: Thank you @Erwin Brandstetter! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You can even generate queries of this form on the fly if the number of items should change regularly.

Comment: @Colin'tHart this is a great idea. Thank you.